# SHOPIFY: How can I check if ANY variant is out of stock

Tags: shopify

I sell t-shirts with multiple variants.

I would like to check if *ANY* of those variants is "Out of Stock". Then if *ANY* of the variants is "Out of Stock" display a message. (the same message, not matter what variant is out of stock)

I know this works to check stock of the *FIRST* variant:

```
{% if product.variants.first.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}

<p style="color:#ff0000">This item is currently out of stock.

Order today, and your item will be shipped in 4-6 weeks.</p>

{% case product.variants.first.inventory_quantity %}

{% when '0' %}

{% else %}

{% endcase %}

{% endif %}
```

But this only checks the first variant. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I am open to handling this in javascript or liquid, but am fairly new to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one surefire way... and you can twist this into whatever pretzels you desire.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}
    <h1>Damn Dawg, this variant be out of stock</h1>
  {% else %}
    ... whatever....
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It sounds like if you only want this message printed once, then it applies to the product and not the variants themselves. In this case, just set a variable to true if anything is out of stock and you can thus print your message just once. The limit:2 suggestion is nonsensical.

eg:

```
{% assign out_of_stock = false %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}
    {% assign out_of_stock = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if out_of_stock == true %}
   <h1>Damn Dog, we're out of beers</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How to display just a single message even if more than a single variant is out of stock?

Comment: Thanks @davidlazar, that is almost perfect, but it repeats the message for every variant that is out of stock. I am just wanting to insert the message once.
I tried using this:
    {% for variant in product.variants limit:1 %}
But then the message doesn't show. Any recommendations?

Comment: @liori adjust the first line of the above code to read: {% for variant in product.variants limit:2 %}, this seems to only display one message for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 there is an HasOutOfStockVariants attribute for GraphQL.